# Sort a list in java into a specific order

Tags: java, string, list, sorting

What is the best way to implement a custom sort for a List?

I have the List of Constants below.

```
ENERGY_POLICY, OBJECTIVE, TRAINING, SEU_REPORT, ENERGY_PERFORMANCE, INTERNAL_AND_EXTERNAL_PARTIES, INTERNAL_AUDIT_REVIEW, LEGAL_REQUIREMENTS_REVIEW, TASKS_REVIEW, CORRECTIVE_ACTIONS
```

I would like to implement a sort function to sort them in the specific order shown below.

```
[OBJECTIVE, ENERGY_POLICY, TRAINING, ENERGY_PERFORMANCE, INTERNAL_AUDIT_REVIEW, LEGAL_REQUIREMENTS_REVIEW, TASKS_REVIEW, SEU_REPORT, CORRECTIVE_ACTIONS, INTERNAL_AND_EXTERNAL_PARTIES]
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How may we know that, for example, `OBJECTIVE` should sort ahead of `ENERGY_POLICY`, and that `CORRECTIVE_ACTIONS` should sort after both of them?

Comment: Please show some code. What are these constants? Are they enums? Strings from a file? static variable names? // How are they "coming in"? // What have you attempted to program and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("OBJECTIVE", "ENERGY_POLICY", "TRAINING", "ENERGY_PERFORMANCE", "INTERNAL_AUDIT_REVIEW",  "LEGAL_REQUIREMENTS_REVIEW", "TASKS_REVIEW, SEU_REPORT", "CORRECTIVE_ACTIONS", "INTERNAL_AND_EXTERNAL_PARTIES");

        Map<String, Integer> ranks = new HashMap<>();

        // Assign rank to each element and store in ranks map. This map will be used for retrieving rank of each element while defining custom sorter
        for (int i =0 ; i< strings.size() ; i++) {
            ranks.put(strings.get(i),i);
        }

        // Now lets take a list which needs to sorted based on above order
        List<String> stringsToBeSorted  = Arrays.asList("ENERGY_POLICY", "OBJECTIVE", "TRAINING", "SEU_REPORT", "ENERGY_PERFORMANCE", "INTERNAL_AND_EXTERNAL_PARTIES", "INTERNAL_AUDIT_REVIEW", "LEGAL_REQUIREMENTS_REVIEW", "TASKS_REVIEW", "CORRECTIVE_ACTIONS");

        stringsToBeSorted.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
                if (ranks.get(str1) == null || ranks.get(str2) == null) {
                    return 0;
                }

                return ranks.get(str1) - ranks.get(str2);
            }
        });
```

**Or with Java 8**

```
        stringsToBeSorted.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(ranks::get));
```

But you need to make sure that **strings** has all the values and there should be no value in **stringsToBeSorted** list which is not present in strings list. as it will throw null pointer exception as its rank retrieved from hashmap is null

Answer (score 0):

You can put each constant in a hash map with the constant as key and the position as the value.

now as and when you receive the constants get the position it should be from the hashmap and based on it create the final list